# IONIC2 not display image from assets on device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

my image (640x 360)
my sclass

```
.auth-home {
background-image: ('./assets/img/auth-background.jpg'); 
background-size: 100%;
background-position-y: 50%;
}
```

i try set background-image:

- background-image: ('assets/img/auth-background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
- background-image: ('../assets/img/auth-background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
- background-image: ('./assets/img/auth-background.jpg');

**but ONLY device not display**

Comment: Add html as well, although `background-image: ('assets/img/auth-background.jpg'); ` will work fine on both android and browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the page scss:

```
page-yourPageName {
    ion-content {
            background-image: url("../assets/img/auth-background.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: And you have to place your image into the `src\assets\img\` folder.